# Couchbase N1QL query with dictionary

Tags: couchbase, sql++

In Couchbase I have documents that contain a dictionary structured like this:

```
{
    "...": "...",
    "members": {
        "*USERID*": {
            "...": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a N1QL Query to get all documents where my user id is in `members`. I have tried many different queries, but I was not able to find a working N1QL query.

What does a N1QL Query look like that selects all documents with a specified user id as a key in the `members` map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT d.*
FROM default AS d
WHERE d.`members`.["myuserid"] IS NOT NULL;
```

OR

```
SELECT d.*
FROM default AS d
WHERE ANY n IN OBJECT_NAMES(d.`members`) SATISFIES n = "myuserid" END;
```

OR

```
SELECT d.*
FROM default AS d
WHERE ANY n:v IN d.`members` SATISFIES n = "myuserid" END;
```